# Trying to attain confidentiality as well as integrity with RSA("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding") using Cipher class in Java

Tags: encryption, java, rsa

After I encrypt using sender's private key, I get the byte array of ciphertext (128 bytes). Now I intend to encrypt it again with the receiver's public key for confidentiality. Initializing Cipher object with the new key and in encrypt mode, when I try to generate the second cipher (using the ciphertext byte array obtained earlier), I get:

`Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 117 bytes`

Assuming that there is a limit to the number of bytes that can be encrypted, what would be a good way for me to proceed?

In short - how to encrypt the result of `Cipher.doFinal()` with a different key?

Comment: How big is your RSA key? And do you know how a hybrid encryption system works?

Comment: indeed RSA has some limits, search for hybrid encryption. there is a [blog with an example](https://gusto77.wordpress.com/2017/10/30/encryption-reference-project/)

Comment: "After I encrypt using sender's private key..." hopefully you are *signing* using the [Signature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Signature.html) class. You could then [hybrid encrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) using AES-GCM and RSA-OAEP. This gives you a sign-encrypt-mac construction that efficiently detects tampering and provides entity authentication.

Comment: Thank you guys! Using the Signature class did it for me. I`ll dig into Hybrid encryption for better understanding.